# Pra que serve o "global::" em C#?

Tags: c#, namespace

Fui editar um código-fonte de uma aplicação que estou escrevendo em C#, que usa GTK+.

Eu tenho algum conhecimento de C#, mas não entendi porque algumas variáveis foram escritas quando eu montei a UI no "arrasta e solta" com o `global::` antes dos nomes.

Veja o trecho do código:

```
private Gtk.VBox vbox2;

private global::Gtk.VBox vbox3;

private global::Gtk.Label tituloLogin;

private global::Gtk.Entry entry1;

private global::Gtk.Entry entry2;
```

Pra que serve esse `global::`? O que ele significa?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`global::` faz referência ao namespace global. Por exemplo, você pode redefinir a classe `System`, olha só:

```
class foo
{
    class System
    {

    }    
}
```

Aí, por exemplo, se tu quiser usar `Console.WriteLine()` nesse escopo, sem conflitar, você usa:

```
global::System.Console.WriteLine("teste");
```

Baseei minha resposta nessa [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022441/what-is-global).

Comment: Uma dica, cuidado com o espaçamento em frases, 4 espaços o site formata automaticamente como código.

Comment: Aaaaah obrigado! Já tinha tido problema com isso outra vez

Comment: Só complementando, o equivalente no VB.NET seria `Global.System.Console.WriteLine()`.